# Cantor set is an uncountable set (from Royden Real Analysis).

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

I was reading Cantor set from Royden Real Anlysis
and i have a doubt on this line marked in brackets , unable to identify the $F_{i}$ sets ,Any help!

[image: here is the Proof attached]

Comment: One of the two disjoint intervals whose union is $C_{1}$ can be $[0,\frac{1}{3}] or [\frac{2}{3},1]$ fails to contain $c_{1}$ , what can be $c_{1} \in \textbf{C}$?

Comment: oh i see i think $\textbf{C}$ always contains 0 and 1

Comment: $c_1$ is any element of $C$, When we have disjoint sets, at most one of them contains $c_1$, or in other words at least one of the does **not** contain $c_1$.

Comment: But if i take $F_{1} = [0,1/3]$ and $c_{1} = 1$ then it works but fails when it says that "one of the two disjoint intervals in 2nd step whose union is $F_{1}$" but here it is not equal to $[0,1/3]$,so my choice is incorrect!

Comment: What fails? $c_2$ is some elements of $\bf{C}$, and $F_1$, in your case, if the union of $[0,1/9]$ and $[2/9,1/3]$. One of these sets, which we call $F_2$, does not contain $c_2$, because they are disjoint. The procedure described in the proof can still be done.

Comment: Yes,but how Union of $[0,1/9]$ and $[2/9,1/3]$ equal $[0,1/3] = F_{1}$?

Comment: You are right, that is a typo. After having $F_n$, $F_{n+1}$ should be defined as follows: "In the $n+1$-th step, one of the two disjoint intervals whose union **is contained in** $F_n$ does not contain $c_{n+1}$; Denote it by $F_{n+1}$."

Answer (score 1):

The proof in the book goes **by contradiction**. So, the author **assumes that the Cantor set is indeed countable and has an enumeration $\{c_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$**. Let us take a look at how the Cantor set is created.

At the first step, the construction creates 2 disjoint closed intervals, namely $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$ and $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. The author picks an element, $c_1$ in $C$ and says that this element belongs in either $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$ or $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. This is true as the intervals. If $c_1 \in [0,\frac{1}{3}]$, then let $F_1=[\frac{2}{3},1]$.

Now, we look at the second step. This creates two sub-intervals in $F_1$ **whose union is not $F_1$, as we exclude the middle third in the construction**. The element $c_2$ either belonged in $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$ or one of the disjoint intervals created in this step. If it belonged in $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$, then we can define $F_2$ to be either of the intervals, say the one that contains $1$. If $c_2 \in [\frac{2}{3},1]$, then define $F_2$ to be the interval that is disjoint from $\{c_2\}$.

Proceed in this manner to obtain **a nested collection of closed intervals that contains a point $c$ in the Cantor set that is disjoint from all of $\{c_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$**, which is our required contradiction.